# logout timer php/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript timer to logout the user after a certain period of innactivity (when there is no mouse movement or clicks on the document).

```
document.onkeypress = ResetTimer;
document.onmousemove = ResetTimer;
wait = 10;
function ResetTimer()
{
    time = new moment();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout("Logout()", 60000 * wait); //logout the user with an ajax call
}
```

I also have a session variable which tracks the last time the user has made a php call. If the user hasn't made any request in 10 minutes, the user is logged out. The issue I am having here is that if the user moves on document while staying on the same page, he won't get disconnected by the javascript, but the PHP will on his next request. Would it be a good practice to refresh the session variable with an ajax call after 9 minutes the user is on the same page (since the wait time is 10 minutes)?

Comment: A better pattern to use in session critical apps is to make an AJAX request once a minute or so (during periods of inactivity) to check that the session is still active. If you can store a timestamp when the session will expire, then you can show the user a prompt on the screen to say something like 'Your account will be signed out in X minutes due to inactivity. To keep your session alive, click here'. The button would then make another AJAX request to keep the session alive if required. If a request is made and the session has expired, you can automatically redirect the user back to login.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for the user experience if the only action required to stay logged in would be to be active on the page ?

Comment: That's true, however the session is stored on the server, whilst user activity is solely client-side. This is where the AJAX would be used to bridge the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `window.setInterval()`. Set a callback function to run every 10 minutes. That callback would fire off an Ajax request to the server and request the server-side application to logout the user.

But, whenever the user interacts with the UI, clear the interval and start a new one.

Thus the logout Ajax request will happen once after 10 minutes of inactivity.

```
function callback() {
    // XMLHttpRequest to logout the user.
}

var intervalID = setInterval(callback);

// To cancel the interval and start a new one:
clearInterval(intervalID);
intervalID = window.setInterval(callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do that in the frontend and save requests.

UPDATE:
Well, I hope it is without bugs, it just an example. You don't need the backend for inactivity control its a frontend responsability, if some user dont use javascript you cannot check inactivity too so, inthe worst case is the same, control this from backend its pointless, let javascript do all the work. Disconnect someone due inactivity its not a security thing, you dont need the backend.

Here is how you do that.

```
(function(d) {
  var time = 15000 * 60; // 15'
  var timer;

  var setTimer = function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("its time to log out");
      // delete phpsessid
      deleteCookie("PHPSESSID");
    }, time);
  };

  var getEvents = function() {
    var res = [];
    for(var k in d) {
      if(k.indexOf("on") === 0) {
        res.push(k.slice(2).toLowerCase());
      }
    }
    return res;
  };

  var refreshTimer = function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    console.log("clear");
    setTimer();
  };

  var deleteCookie = function(cname) {
    var date = new Date(-1);
    date.setTime(date.getTime());
    d.cookie = cname + "=1; " + "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  };

  getEvents().forEach(function(evt) {
    d.addEventListener(evt, function() {
      refreshTimer();
    });
  });

  setTimer();
})(document);
```

Comment: How would I send data to my server from JavaScript on a page refresh ? I don't think that is possible.

Comment: If the user refresh, that count like an action and you have to refresh the timer, right?
Let me understand you, you want to disconnect the user if he is inactive. In order to do that you check that the user make at least one action in a range of ten minutes. ok?
If he refresh, he is still there... so, you have to refresh the timer... so, I dont see the problem... you dont need the backend checks if he is still there, do all with JS.

Comment: In fact, if the user is inactive, delete the session cookie with JS, and he will be disconnected automatically because PHP cannot recognize him without that cookie. Or token if you modify that..., or, less elegant, send an ajax request to disconnect him... but, the point is, you dont need to check times in backend.

Comment: The issue here is that if the client stays on the same page for 15 minutes without being disconnected because he moves the mouse and he refresh the page, the php will see that he hasn't made any php request in the last 10 minutes, so it will logout the user.